# What is a good pattern to preserve custom properties created in a Knockout extension?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I currently have two Knockout extension functions. One  adds a member to the Observable while the other intercepts the read and write operations.

When combining the extension methods the order of application has an unwanted effect.

Simplified code examples below.

```
ko.extenders.format = function(target) {
    var result = ko.computed(function(){
        return "$" + target();
    });

    target.formatted = result;

   return target;
};

ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var current = parseFloat(target());
           return current.toFixed(precision);
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            newValue = parseFloat(newValue);
            target(newValue.toFixed(precision));
        }
    });

    return result;
};
```

In the numeric method I can check for the formatted member and assign it to the new computed but I don't want to give it knowledge of the other method. This also won't be maintainable if I decide to add more members off the observable or extensions.

```
if(target.hasOwnProperty("formatted")){
    result.formatted = target.formatted;
}
```

Heres a fiddle without the hasOwnProperty fix. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gs5JM/2/

Notice that MyValue4 - Format: is blank due to the order of extender application and the loss of the formatted member.

Is there a better pattern to achieve the same end result and make the code more flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `format` extender refers to original observable and `numeric` creates a new one. So `format` and `numeric` work with completely different observables. Looks like you should consider to return original observable in both cases.

I would rewrite your `numeric` this way:

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {

    ko.computed(function(){
        var current = parseFloat(target());
        target(isNaN(current) ? 0 : current.toFixed(precision));
    });

    return target;
};
```

Anonymous `computed` will create a subscription to `target` value changes with immediate evaluation. The evaluation function will try to parse a value and reassign precised numeric value to the target observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/gs5JM/3/

Note: [**You should not care about possible circular dependency because KO will not re-evaluate `computed` while it's already evaluating**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#note_why_circular_dependencies_arent_meaningful).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't aware that an anonymous ko.computed would work that way, but it does make sense.

Comment: This works great for observables and computed fields with a write method, but fails when its a computed with only a read method. In the initial numeric extender I included both a read and write function so I could use it in both scenarios. Do you have a suggestion if it's not a writeable observable?

Comment: It will be very strange scenario when you need an extender to write into read-only observables. Could you explain in details?

Comment: I don't need it to write into a read only observable. I just wanted a single extension method to handle both read and write operations if they happen. After seeing your answer and trying a few different things I think I'll be going with two separate extenders. One to manage the value coming into the observable and another to take care of the reading.

Comment: Ok. FYI you can easily check writeable observables with `ko.isWriteableObservable` function.